# babel with sub js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

i'm new at Babel and i have some question with using Babel inside of node.js. There is a file named 'app.js', main file of my node app. so i transpile 'app.js' with:

```
babel app.js --out-file app-compiled.js
```

and it looks good. but the problem is sub files. in "app.js", there is a syntax that load external javascript file.

```
import MyComponent from './components/mycomponent';
```

and inside of "./components/mycomponent' is:

```
...
var MyComponent = { ... };
...
export default MyComponent;
```

and if i start 'app-compiled.js', it has error because sub file using 'import/export' and node don't know what they are.

is there a way to automatically compile sub files or like sent to client, is there a way to bundle whole ES2015 node apps to single JavaScript file that node can understand?

it will be very appreciate it to give me some advice!

p.s. sorry, i forgot to mentioned: i created .babelrc with

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

babel is working well, but how to make the load external JS used ES2015 in node app with babel?

Comment: Are you building something for node use only or something for the browser? Node doesn't understand the ES6 `import` `export` syntax yet so you need to continue using `require`, and to get it to work in the browser you will need to use webpack or browserify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel doesn't support ES2015/ES6 out of the box. For that, you need to enable the `es2015` preset.

It's outlined [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/), but basically you need to do this in your project directory:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
$ echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc
```

After that, you can run the `babel` command the same way you're doing now and it should translate `import/export` to the ES5-equivalents.

Comment: oh, i'am sorry. i forgot to mention it, i already created .babelrc with { "presets": ["es2015", "react"] }. babel is actually work, but my question is how to load external javascript used ES2015 with babel?

Comment: If you want to place all code into a single file, you need a bundler like Browserify or Webpack (which have Babel-support). Alternatively, you can have Babel transpile all ES6 files to ES5 and have it write them to a separate directory (`--out-dir`).